# How to prove $(x_1+\frac{1}{x_1})\cdots(x_n+\frac{1}{x_n})\ge (x_1+\frac{1}{x_2})\cdots(x_n+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}})(x_1+\frac{1}{x_n}),n\ge 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

Recently, when I self-learned Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th by Kenneth Rosen, I did only the even-numbered exercises which the author offers the detailed description than the odd ones because the odd ones and the corresponding even ones are very similar.

I was stuck at exercise 5-Supplementary-36 which is related with induction. The problem is

> Use mathematical induction to prove that if $x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n$ are positive real numbers with $n\ge 2$, then $$
> (x_1+\frac{1}{x_1})(x_2+\frac{1}{x_2})\cdots(x_n+\frac{1}{x_n})\ge (x_1+\frac{1}{x_2})(x_2+\frac{1}{x_3})\cdots(x_n+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}})(x_1+\frac{1}{x_n})
> $$

The answer says

> It will be convenient to clear fractions by multiplying both sides by the product of all the $x_s$’s ; this makes the desired inequality
> $$
> (x_1^2 + 1)(x_2^2 + 1)\cdots(x_n^2 + 1) \ge (x_1 x_2 + 1)(x_2 x_3 + 1) ···(x_{n−1}x_n + 1)(x_n x_1 + 1).
> $$ ...
>
> Because of the *cyclic* form of this inequality, we can *without loss of generality* assume that $x_{n+1}$ is the largest (or tied for the largest) of all the given numbers

Q:

However, when I swap between arbitrary $x_i,x_j$ where $1\le i,j\le n$, then $(x_1 x_2 + 1)(x_2 x_3 + 1) ···(x_{n−1}x_n + 1)(x_n x_1 + 1)$ will *change* value. Then how does the above the WLOG(without loss of generality) assumption work? If the assumption has some problems, how to prove the above theorem?

Comment: That answer does not claim that you cannot swap two values, only that you can do a *cyclic permutation* of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$

Comment: You can change $(x_1,...,x_n)$ to $(x_2,...,x_n,x_1)$, that's what "cycle" means.

Comment: Thanks for the above comments. I understand the problem now. Mark this question as solved here.

Comment: The simpler method is to NOT use the induction. Just remind that
$$(x_1^2+1)(x_2^2 +1) \ge (x_1x_2+1)^2$$

Comment: The exercise wants them to use induction.

Comment: @NN2 your comment is specific to $n=2$, then how to make it work for $n\ge 3$? Could you say more detailedly?

Comment: For the case $n \ge 3$, just do
$$LHS^2 = \prod_{cyc}\left((x_i^2+1)(x_{i+1}^2 +1)\right) \ge\prod_{cyc}(x_ix_{i+1}+1)^2 = RHS^2$$

Comment: Although I didn't ask for one different solution from the book, it is helpful. Thanks for offering this new method which is not explicitly stated in the book answer.

Comment: Put the numbers on a Circle. Starting at which-ever number , we can name those numbers $x_1$ to $$x_n$ : that is what **Cyclic Order** means. It will not change the value here. Hence , it is WLOG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ denote the difference between left-hand side and right-hand side of the desired inequality. Then
$$
 f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = f(x_2, \ldots, x_n, x_1) \, ,
$$
i.e. the function is invariant under a *cylic permutation* of its arguments.

With a finite number of such cyclic permutations the largest (or smallest) of the arguments can be moved to the first (or last) position, as desired.

It is *not* claimed that $f$ is invariant under an arbitrary permuation of the arguments (which is a much stronger property).